# Document creation timestamp (server-time) in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase and firestore, creating a single-page app, I was wondering how can I store the document creation time with the document, representing the server-side time. When I changed my system time to an incorrect time and then ran the code below, it was storing the same (incorrect) timestamp for both `clientDate` and `serverTimestamp` fields.

I tried the following (Firebase JavaScript SDK version 9.0.2):

```
import { addDoc, collection, Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../index';

export const storeSomething = async () => {
    const data = {
        clientDate: new Date(),
        serverTimestamp: Timestamp.now(),
    };
    
    const someCol = collection(db, 'somecollection');
    const docRef = await addDoc(someCol, data);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Timestamp.now()` function returns the current client-side time, so is indeed sensitive to clock skew and manipulation.

To write a [server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_9), use:

- in v9/modular syntax: `serverTimestamp()`
- in v8/compat syntax: `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`
- in the Admin SDK: `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`